# Vue component not reactive until value in template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a child component in Vue. I also use Vuex for some values.

When I click something in the parent component, the child component should be triggered. I do that by sending an `active` (bool) as prop to the child component.

In the `updated` method I do what needs to be done when the component is triggered.

**Problem**

In order for `updated` to be triggerd, I need to add `active` to my template. Else it's not triggered. So my really hackish solution right now is to use `v-show="!active || active"` which says, "always show the div".

How can I trigger the component without a hack like this? I don't need the `active` value in my template.

**Complete child component**

```php
Vue.component('p-inline-readonly', {
  mixins: [ table_mixin ],
  props: {
    value: [ String, Number ],
    active: Boolean
  },
  updated() {
    this.reset();
    this.refocus();
  },
  template: /*html*/ `
    <div class="slot p-inline-readonly">
      <div class="presentation" v-show="!active || active">
        {{value}}
      </div>
    </div>
  `
});
```

Comment: Could you give a default value to the prop? `active: {default: false, type: Boolean}`

Comment: @kevmc Good idea but it did not work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could watch `active` and trigger an update:

```
watch: {
    active: function(val, oldVal) {
      this.$forceUpdate();
    },
}
```

You may also add a key to the child component:

```
<p-inline-readonly :key="active" ... >
```

This will make the component rerender when active change, but won't call the `updated` hook so you would need to move its logic to a different hook like `mounted`

Comment: Looks nice! Which solution would you use of the two?

Comment: @JensTörnell maybe the first one to avoid rebuilding the whole component